# Installation problem with wordpress xampp

Tags: errors, rss, local-installation, curl, proxy

I have installed wordpress in my xampp server. everything looks great. I am using proxy so i have added below snippet in wp_config.php to use proxies.

```
/* Configure proxy Server */
define('WP_PROXY_HOST', '192.56.14.2');
define('WP_PROXY_PORT', '5656');
define('WP_PROXY_USERNAME', 'xxxx');
define('WP_PROXY_PASSWORD', 'xxxx');
```

I think there is problem in installation. So I am editing the question. I install WP and set proxies like i said. then I go to Dashboard and there is news section which shows the error like following.

[image: Wordpress news section]

when i try to INSTALL any theme. It shows following Error.

```
Installation failed: Download failed. cURL error 56: Proxy CONNECT aborted
```

[image: Shown in this image]

I couldn't find much on this.Any help would be so awesome!

Comment: Hi, Are you using a Apple laptop or system if so check this post as it is down to user permissions , https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/261027/installing-wordpress-theme-unit-data/261032#comment387242_261032
I switched to Mamp for this reason as updating to newer version of xamp broke mysql databases.

Comment: Hello @sam thank you for your reply but im not using apple laptop. I am trying to install WP on win7.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set up  - Implements a proxy/gateway for Apache:
https://gist.github.com/ralphcrisostomo/4036231

More explanation here:
https://rada.neocities.org/xampp-windows-proxy-server.html